# How to navigate to a page after the splash screen loads and before the grid template app loads C# XMAL Windows 8 store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

this is my first time to use stackoverflow :) ,

I was working with grid template app in windows 8 store app and i wanted to add welcome page after the splash screen loaded , to do that i tried to add this statement

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage));
```

to the `OnLaunched` method that was created by default with the grid template in the `App.xmal.cs`. after i created the `Welcomepage` it self and i created a button in the welcome page to navigate to the `GroupedItemsPage`.

My logic isn't working.

this is the default method code in the App.xmal.cs if that will help

```
 protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        //Associate the frame with a SuspensionManager key                                
        SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "AppFrame");

        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            // Restore the saved session state only when appropriate
            try
            {
                await SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
            }
            catch (SuspensionManagerException)
            {
                //Something went wrong restoring state.
                //Assume there is no state and continue
            }
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter
        if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        }
    }
    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: what is the code that `isn't working`? what happens after you call `rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage));`?

Comment: Do you get navigated to the `WelcomePage` or not? In your code you go to the `GroupedItemsPage` instead of the `WelcomePage`.

Comment: Benjamin , i tried to navigate to welcomepage by changing if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GroupedItemsPage), "AllGroups"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        } to if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WelcomePage), "AllGroups"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
        } but when i renavigate to from the WelcomePage to GroupedItemsPage Through button it gives error

Comment: I did IT , Just i forget to add , "AllGroups" to the navigation from